# No backend warning in TexMaker text

Tags: texmaker, warnings

There are two errors over line 1 of my text

1) No "backend" specified, using Biber backend

2) 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.

here is a sample of the document

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \textheight 650pt
    \textwidth 6in
    \voffset -1cm
    \hoffset -0.75cm

    \input epsf
    \def\figin{\epsfcheck\figin}\def\figins{\epsfcheck\figins}
    \def\epsfcheck{\ifx\epsfbox\UnDeFiNeD
    \message{(NO epsf.tex, FIGURES WILL BE IGNORED)}
    \gdef\figin##1{\vskip2in}\gdef\figins##1{\hskip.5in}% blank space instead
    \else\message{(FIGURES WILL BE INCLUDED)}%
    \gdef\figin##1{##1}\gdef\figins##1{##1}\fi}

    \def\figinsert{}
    \def\ifig#1#2#3{\xdef#1{fig.~\the\figno}
    \writedef{#1\leftbracket fig.\noexpand~\the\figno}%
    \figinsert\figin{\centerline{#3}}\medskip\centerline{\vbox{\baselineskip12pt
    \advance\hsize by -1truein\center\footnotesize{  Fig.~\the\figno.} #2}}
    \bigskip\endinsert\global\advance\figno by1}
    \def\footnotefont{}\def\endinsert{}



    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{slashed}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}



    \begin{document}

    text

    \end{document}
```

Comment: A man prayed to God every night to win the lottery.  He never did.  In heaven tells God how strong his faith was, and he could not believe God let him down like that.  God replies, "you needed to meet me half way... you had to buy a ticket."  Likewise, for us to help you with code, you need to meet us half way and provide us with some code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What would be useful to see? Because the 4 lines of text that are causing the problem don't have any commands in. Just plain text.

Comment: Things like document class, packages used, the specific text that causes the issue. Generally, the questioner (called the OP) posts a Minimum Working Example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, in which the problem, boiled down to its essence, can be demonstrated.  This saves work for the people otherwise willing to assist you.

Comment: I've managed to use flush left to remove the badbox warnings but, there are two warnings on the first line still.
1) No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
2) 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.

Comment: Your problem complexity is not trivial, now that we know it involves things like `biber`.  *Really*, you posting code to get us started is the only way to help you.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ftex.stackexchange.com+No+%22backend%22+specified%2C+using+Biber+backend.

Comment: ive amended the question and shown my preamble

Comment: When posting multiline code, after you copy it into the question, highlight the code block and click on the `{}` icon at the top of the edit box.  It indents the code 4 spaces, and displays for the world as a code block (I edited and did that for you).  For inline code snippets, surround the snippet with backticks (grave accent).  That will display it as inline code.  Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 1):

They are just warnings, or in the first case more of a message than a warning. They are not errors, which would cause compilation to stop. Both of them are from the `biblatex` package.

1. Missing backend. `biblatex` allows for different bibliography backends. A backend is in this context the program that reads the citations from auxiliary files, collects the necessary entries from the `.bib` file, sorts the output and writes a `.bbl` file that contains the bibliography. If no backend is specified, `biber` is assumed, and the information written by `biblatex` is designed for `biber`. To remove the warning, add `backend=biber` in the options for `biblatex`, i.e. `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`.

   That is of course if you want to use `biber`, if you wish to use `bibtex`, it's `backend=bibtex`.
2. `csquotes` is package for formatting quotes, with a language dependent style. `biblatex` recommends to also load this, i.e. have `\usepackage{csquotes}` in the preamble.  If you add that, the warning goes away.